# Atomic operations on shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Assume I have `shared_ptr<T> a` and two threads running concurrently where one does:

```
a.reset();
```

and another does:

```
auto b = a;
```

if the operations are atomic, then I either end up with two empty shared_ptrs or `a` being empty and `b` pointing to what was pointed to by `a`. I am fine with either outcome, however, due to the interleaving of the instructions, these operations might not be atomic. Is there any way I can assure that?

To be more precise I only need `a.reset()` to be atomic.

**UPD**: as pointed out in the comments my question is silly if I don't get more specific. It is possible to achieve atomicity with a mutex. However, I wonder if, on the implementation level of `shared_ptr`, things are already taken care of. From cppreference.com, copy assignment and copy constructors are thread-safe. So `auto b = a` is alright to run without a lock. However, from [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) it's unclear if `a.reset()` is also thread-safe.

**UPD1**: it would be great if there is some document that specifies which methods of shared_ptr are thread-safe. From cppreference:

> If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a **non-const member function** of shared_ptr then a data race will occur

It is unclear to me which of the methods are non-const.

Comment: If you're dealing with threads then you should have heard of *semaphores* and *mutexes* and *conditional variables*. If not, then time to do some more research.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, I need to be more specific. Of course, I could use those but I want to know if these operations are thread-safe for shared_ptr. Let me specify that.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` is like any other object when it comes to threading. If you are reading and writing you need synchronization.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think that's true because some level of synchronization is implemented for operations like copy constructor or assignment leading me to believe that other functions might already have thread-safety guaranteed. I agree that with any object I can add another layer of synchronization on top of it. I don't want to do extra work if that is guaranteed by the compiler though.

Comment: Moreover, in terms of efficiency I can't believe that I will beat shared_ptr under-the-hood synchronization if it exists for `reset()`.

Comment: _auto b = a is alright to run without a lock_ I'm not sure that is true.  If `a` is being mutated by another thread then you might wind up with `b` in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @PaulSanders from cppreference: "All member functions (including **copy constructor and copy assignment**) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object." So if I do `a = make_shared<T>()` and `auto b = a` in different threads, it's ok.

Comment: Not sure about `a.reset()` and in general not sure about other methods. Looking for some documentation that can answer these questions.

Comment: @PaulSanders upon thinking about it, I admit you're right.

Comment: @Galik I read about that too and I think there are three things that I worry about when it comes to shared_ptr: the control block, the object that the pointer points to, and the pointer itself. Of course when I modify the data that a shared_ptr points to I will add locks to ensure synchronization. I know that operations affecting the control blocks are fine, too. What I wonder is if changing the pointer itself should be synchronized, like in my example.

Comment: From a layman's perspective, `a.reset()` sets the pointer to nullptr and decreases the value in the control block by one atomically. `auto b = a` sets the pointer of `b` to the same one as that of `a` and increases the counter in the control block by one. Is there a race condition here or is C++ standard guaranteeing that that won't happen?

Comment: Both *assignment* and *reset* are defined in terms of `std::shared_ptr::swap`.

Comment: No operation that can affect the value of `use_count()` may cause a data race. The standard says: *"Changes in use_count() do not reflect modifications that can introduce data races."*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the other thread use a `weak_ptr`.  The lock() operation on weak pointer is documented to be atomic.

Create:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
std::weak_ptr<A> a_weak = std::weak_ptr<A>(a);
```

Thread 1:

```
a.reset();
```

Thread 2:

```
b = a_weak.get();
if (b != nullptr)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` is what some call a "thread-compatible" class, meaning that as long as each *instance* of a `std::shared_ptr<T>` can only have one thread calling its member functions at a given point in time, such member function invocations do not cause race conditions, even if multiple threads are accessing `shared_ptr`s that share ownership with each other.

`std::shared_ptr<T>` is not a *thread-safe* class; it is not safe for one thread to call a non-`const` method of an `std::shared_ptr<T>` instance while another thread is also accessing *the same instance*. If you need potentially concurrent reads and writes to not race, then synchronize them using a mutex.

Comment: Can I ask for the source that confirms this? Not that I don't believe you, but I just want to know more and read the full source to get a better understanding.

Comment: @nhtrnm http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races implies that standard library classes to be thread-compatible when they're accessed through their member functions. http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#4 implies that this extends to `shared_ptr`s even when they share ownership of an object.